# How can I repair broken softwares?

Tags: dependencies, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg as [Documented here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FFmpeg#Source_Build) . but some errors are accurates when I want install on terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfaac-dev : Depends: libfaac0 (= 1.28-6) but 1.28-6+ppa2 is to be installed
 libmp3lame-dev : Depends: libmp3lame0 (= 3.99.5+repack1-3ubuntu1) but 3.99.5+repack1-7~trusty is to be installed
 libvorbis-dev : Depends: libvorbis0a (= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1) but 1.3.4-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libvorbisenc2 (= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1) but 1.3.4-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libvorbisfile3 (= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1) but 1.3.4-1~trusty1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

> -f, --fix-broken
>          Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
>          This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
>          to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
>          specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
>          is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
>          itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
>          system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
>          so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
>          using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
>          Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
>          situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.

Running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Should repair any broken dependencies.

Comment: It will "repair" them by removing what was planned to install.

Comment: '0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.'
Is the return of 'sudo apt-get install -f' command

Comment: @Huseyin: Try this then instead `sudo apt-get remove -f`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda problem was not solved. Same problem exist there. Is there any alternative solution for this case?

Comment: @Huseyin: Try running the command: `sudo apt-get install libfaac0 libmp3lame0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2libvorbisfile3`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  `libfaac0 is already the newest version.` this code was displayed for all packages.

Comment: @Huseyin: Try to remove all these packages then, and install the older versions that they speak of.